# different outputs in unpack function in python

Tags: python, unpack

I am observing a different output in the unpack function of python when I accept the string input from the console and when I read the string input from a variable.

I read the string input from the variable, input:

```
>>> import struct
>>> input="\x0d\x00\x00\x00"
>>> print struct.unpack("I",input)[0]
13
```

I read the string input from the console:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import struct
>>> print struct.unpack("I",sys.stdin.read(4))[0]
\x0d\x00\x00\x00
1680898140
```

The input string is the same but the output is different. Does it interpret the input read from the console in a different way? How can I get the same input by reading the data from console?

Comment: The question is, why are you typing in literal Python escape codes in the second example? In your first example, you are creating a Python string literal, which means Python first gets to interpret the escape codes..

Answer (score 1):

`"\x0d\x00\x00\x00"` (from the first code) is different from `r"\x0d\x00\x00\x00"` (== `"\\x0x\\x00\x00\x00"`) from the second code.

```
>>> struct.unpack("I", '\x0d\x00\x00\x00')[0]
13
>>> struct.unpack("I", r'\x0d\x00\x00\x00'[:4])[0]
1680898140
```

Try following:

```
>>> struct.unpack("I", sys.stdin.readline().decode('string-escape')[:4])[0]
\x0d\x00\x00\x00
13
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are unpacking the wrong data...

```
>>> struct.unpack('I','\\x0d')[0]
1680898140
```

your call to `sys.stdin.read(4)` reads only 4 characters: `\`, `x`, `0` and `d`.

```
>>> import sys
>>> import struct
>>> value = raw_input().decode('string-escape')
\x0d\x00\x00\x00
>>> print struct.unpack("I", value)[0]
13
```